# Drawing a graph using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to draw a graph using networkx

```
graph = thisdict['data']['graph']

dict_edges = graph['edges']

edges = []

for edge in dict_edges:
    edges.append((edge['source']['node_id'], edge['target']['node_id']))

print('Source:\t\t\t     Target:\n')
    
for edge in edges:
    print(str(edge))

print('\n')

dict_nodes = graph['nodes']

nodes = {}

for node in dict_nodes:
    nodes[node['id']] = node['name']

print('Node ID:\t\t    Node Name:\n')

for key, value in nodes.items():
    print("'%s':'%s'" %(key, value))
```

The output:

```
Source:                                Target:

('61697b94f74c92a808641ba3', '61697b95f74c92a808641ba4')

('61697b94f74c92a808641ba3', '61697b96f74c92a808641ba5')

('61697b95f74c92a808641ba4', '61697b96f74c92a808641ba6')

('61697b96f74c92a808641ba6', '61697b97f74c92a808641ba7')

('61697b96f74c92a808641ba5', '61697b97f74c92a808641ba7')

('61697b97f74c92a808641ba7', '61697b98f74c92a808641ba8')

('61697b98f74c92a808641ba8', '61697b98f74c92a808641ba9')


Node ID:            Node Name:

'61697b94f74c92a808641ba3':'S3 connector'

'61697b95f74c92a808641ba4':'loader 1'

'61697b96f74c92a808641ba5':'loader 2'

'61697b96f74c92a808641ba6':'sampler 1'

'61697b97f74c92a808641ba7':'concator'

'61697b98f74c92a808641ba8':'sampler 2'

'61697b98f74c92a808641ba9':'splitter'
```

I'm trying to draw a graph using Networkx. I need to use these nodes and connecting them using the edges above.

The code

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

for edge in edges:
    G.add_edges_from([(edge['source']),(edge['target'])])

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = 1000)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist = G.edges(), edge_color = 'red')

for node in nodes:
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, nodes)

plt.show()
```

The error:

```
----> 4     G.add_edges_from([(edge['source']),(edge['target'])])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str*
```

Comment: As you showed in the first code block, each `edge` is a tuple. And as the error says: you can't index into a tuple with a string like `edge['source']`. You need something like `edge[0]` (indexing the first element).

Comment: edges seems to be a list of tuples, simply doing `G.add_edges_from(edges)` should do the job.

Comment: @Julkar9 Worked! I really thank you.